# Is there a shortcut key to switch between split panes in visual studio/management studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

When I have a file open in visual studio/sql server management studio and have it split in to two panes, I'd like to be able to switch between the panes without having to reach for the mouse. Does anyone know if a shortcut key exists for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SSMS: right-click toolbars, customize. Under categories, select Window, then under Commands select "Next Split Pane". Drag to toolbar. Right-click and change name to "Next Split P&ane". You can now use alt-a to change split pane.

Comment: Neither this nor `F6` key is working for me in VS2008. I checked the Key board shortcut and `F6` is correctly assigned to `Window.NextSplitPane`. Even clicking on the toolbar button as suggested above is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Add another question, try a different keyboard shortcut, or try writing a macro. http://codeidol.com/csharp/visual-studio-2005/The-Visual-Studio-Automation-Object-Model/Windows/ may help.

Answer (score 33):

<kbd>F6</kbd> is your friend.

Comment: To my surprise, in SQL Server Management Studio the behavior is somewhat different; F6 will jump between the query editor and the message window in the bottom. It will not jump between the panes in a split query window. In VS F6 will jump between source/design panes for a aspx or html file, as well as splits in code windows.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this further

Comment: F6 is Build in Visual Studio with the default C# Development Settings.

Comment: And before someone looks what it's bound to in the Visual C# keymap - it isn't by default. But you can assign whatever you want to `Window.NextSplitPane` as Steve said below. I used Ctrl+(key above tab)

Answer (score 19):

I think you can assign this by going to *Tools -> Options -> Keyboard* and searching for *SplitPane*. You should be able to assign shortcut keys for the following values:

Window.NextSplitPane
Window.PreviousSplitPane

Comment: NextSplitPane will cycle among the splits, I think.

Comment: Ctrl + W, Ctrl + Tab and Ctrl + W, Ctrl + Shift + Tab proved intuitive for next and previous window split for me as Ctrl + Tab and Ctrl + Shift + Tab are for next and previous open document.

Answer (score 7):

CTRL+F6 will cycle through your files and across panes.

Comment: Which is `Window.NextDocumentWindow` in Visual Studio's `Tools >>> Options >>> Keyboard` pane if you want to reassign (or, in my case, assign `Ctrl-F6` back).

Answer (score 3):

On Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2012, I figured out that it is the combination of Ctrl+Shift+UpArrow(or DownArrow). :-)

Comment: Perfect. This should be the actual answer. Thank you. 

Answer (score 1):

This was not easy for me for some reason.  This method finally worked (similar to Steve Dignan's answer above but I don't have enough rep to comment yet).

In VS 2012, Tools, Options, Environment, Keyboard.
"Apply the following additional keyboard scheme" set to "Visual C# 2005".
"Use new shortcut in" set to 'Global'.
Enter "splitpane" in "Show commands containing" to get only the 2 desired commands.
Select the first one and remove any shortcuts already assigned. 
Click inside the "Press shortcut keys" box and use "Ctrl + Alt + Up Arrow" for prev and down arrow for next.
If either of those shortcut chords are currently used by something else, you may need to search on that command and remove it from there.  Then come back to the split pane commands and Assign.
Don't forget to close VS before you open another instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2010 (maybe others as well) `F6` will work to jump between split panes if *Tools -> Options -> Keyboard* **does not** use the *Visual C# 2005* keyboard layout additionally (which was the case for me for I-don't-know-why reasons - maybe I said yes to an installer/first-start question a long time ago).

Of course you will no longer be able to build your project with `F6` afterwards. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2012:   Tools -> Options -> Keyboard -> search by Window.Split and add a new shortcut.