# Visual Studio 2012 changes focus to design pane

Tags: visual-studio-2012

when you change documents (ctrl+tab) on WPF (maybe others too) the focus always goes to the design pane.
So imagine - you edit XAML and want to copy an existing element from another existing document.
You are in Doc1 XAML type somethinng next you switch to Doc2 where you have been in XAML pane before.
Now the Designer of Doc2 gets the focus. Since I left the focus in XAML I use shift arrow to select some XAML text - instead the focused control is moved.
The same when you switch back.

VS 2012 simply doesn't remember in which pane (XAML / design) the focus has been.
This is really hard for me since I do this often - and now I have always to grab the mouse and switch back to XAML after changing the current document.

Any idea if this can be change? Or at least if there is a keyboard shortcut to swicht from one XAML to another.

Comment: Im not sure as I dont have VS 2012 here but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034392/is-there-a-shortcut-key-to-switch-between-split-panes-in-visual-studio-managemen  it worked for me in VS2010.

Comment: Just went to do this and realise I had read the question wrong I think.  I think the shortcut you are looking for is Shift-F7

Comment: On my computer, the focus stays in the text editor when using ctrl-tab to navigate between documents.

Comment: Sometimes it does it alos for me
But most of the time not - I couldn't figure out why.
In VS2010 - focus just stays where it was.

Comment: This is unexpectedly irritating. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nothing related to the F6 or F7 keys as suggested by other answers on stackoverflow seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for **Shift+ESC**. This closes the current window that is in focus in Visual Studio Eg. Solution Explorer, Output Window, Immediate window, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't pressing Shift+F7 help you?

Comment: No
And it changes -- sometimes it works (Focus stays in XML code) but most of the time I land in designer

Answer (score 0):

I was getting so frustrated by this but I finally found a work around! If you have a pane collapsed then and only then shift+F7 seems to switch between the panes. The work around drawback is that you only get to view one pane (Designer or XAML) at a time. For some reason Shift+F7 doesn't work when in split view. Small caveat, I am in Visual Studio 2015. I suspect the behavior is the same for 2012. This answer may be more relevant to whomever comes across this knowing that it works for vs2015 though.

Hit Collapse View
[image: XAML Designer Diagram]

Another thing that is important to note is how to ensure one pane is collapsed.
Visual studio seems to remember the last view you had the XAML designer in for that particular XAML file. You can change them per file and visual studio will remember or you can change the default mode a .xaml file will open in by going to (in visual-studio-2015) the tools menu item. Then click options, which opens the options window. Then click XAML Designer, which is the last option in pane on the left of options window. Then change the selected item in the combobox labeled Default Document View from Split View to Source View.

When I first changed the default I didn't think it worked; changing the default will not overwrite the settings saved for the last document view you were in for a particular file. The only way I found to have the default applied was to just wipe out my .suo file for the solution and close visual studio. Deleting the .suo file and closing and re-opening the solution didn't work. I had to delete the file and close visual studio, open visual studio back up, and reload the solution.

The .suo file is hiding in a hidden folder called ".vs" inside the solution folder. I initially just renamed it .suo.bak just in case something happened that I didn't like, but once I reloaded the solution and everything was fine I deleted it.