# Is there a command/hotkey to switch subpanes of a vertically split editor window in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, hotkeys, editing

Having split an editor window horizontally, I want to be able to switch back and forth between the 2 subpanes without using hotkeys. I haven't found which (if any) command would do this. If there is, I'll just use the predefined hotkey (if there is one).

I gather that VSCode already has predfined keys to switch between the subpanes of a window after splitting it, but can't find an equivalent in VS2017.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034392/is-there-a-shortcut-key-to-switch-between-split-panes-in-visual-studio-managemen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the command Windows.NextSplitPane; by default this is globally assigned as <kbd>F6</kbd>.